# How to grab an <input> value from typeahead.js results?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js, bloodhound

This is my current code:

html:

```
<form>
    <div>
      <input class="state tt-input">
    </div>
    <div>
      <input class="state tt-input">
    </div>
    ...
</form>
```

jquery/typeahead.js implementation:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

    var bh = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        prefetch: {
          url: '/get_states/',
          prefetch: function(settings) {
            settings.type = "GET";
            return settings;
          }, 
        },
      });

  $('.state').typeahead({
      hint: true,
      highlight: true,
      minLength: 1
    },
    {
      name: 'states',
      source: bh,
  });

  var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
      return function findMatches(q, cb) {
      var matches, substringRegex;

      // an array that will be populated with substring matches
      matches = [];

      // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
      substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

      // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
      // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
      $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
        if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
          matches.push(str);
        }
      });

      cb(matches);
    };
  };
```

Question 1: I would like to grab the value of the state that the user ultimately selects. I have the following so far it doesn't seem to work.

```
  $('form').on("change", ".state", function(e){
    var $contextualDiv = $(e.target).closest('div');
    var $state = $contextualDiv.find('.state');
    console.log($state.val())
    ...
```

$state.val() seems to be null or blank.

Question 2: The code seems to only allow typeahead on the first div, not the second. But it should look at the input on a relative basis. So not sure why it's not working. thanks.

Comment: Not sure about question 2, but for question 1 - use `$(this).val()` to get the value of the input

Comment: $(this) should equal to $state? Why does one work and the other doesn't?

Comment: Yes, `$(this)` should be either one of the `.state` elements - and it appears to be working for me https://jsfiddle.net/7zj374hn/

Comment: If I remove the typeahead element, then it works. But if I include it then it doesn't. So it has something to do with typeaheads response.